# Jquery height incorrect when set previously

Tags: jquery, height

I have made a separate part of a website which we are loading into the joomla site through an iframe but I want to adjust the height of the container of the iframe.

Therefore I am trying to retrieve the height of my html with the following code which works fine (calling this from inside the iframe):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(document).height();
    alert( height );
});
```

The height is alerted correctly at all pages.

The problem rises when I adjust the height of the iframe container. When I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(document).height();
    alert( height );
    parent.document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = height + 'px';
});
```

Now the height will be the same or larger than the previous height, so when you go from a page with the height of 900px to one of 500px the height will remain 900px (in the alert as well). From small to big works just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you are using jquery, you can use just

$("#blockrandom").height(height);

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that doesn't solve te problem unfortunately and when I do this, the resize doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found that once the height is adjusted, using native property or jQuery makes no difference, the resultant height value does not appear to reflect the new values set. So to dynamically adjust elements during same page interaction, I have, so far, had to resort to a heuristic for the height.

I end up evaluating the content within the element and constructing an acceptable, if not perfectly accurate, proxy height value. For example, let's say I have a box with an original set of 22 label-fields.

As the user adjusts parent values or options, I may end up with any number of resultant fields between 0 and the full 22.

So if I have 10 left after some user event, I run a function that counts up the visible elements and calculates a height. So 10 fields x 22pixels means I readjust the containing element to about 220 pixels.

Specifically, I have an abstracted function into which I assign a default height, a base height (which allows for some always exposed non-adjustable elements like text/instructions, whatever), and the element height multiplier.

On load and between events I set the element container to the default height. After counting the variable elements, I calculate the value by multiplying the variable elements by the multiplier and adding that to the base height.

So far that is the best I have been able to do and is fairly simple. Using jQuery selectors, it only takes a few lines to count and a couple more to calculate and set the height.

NB: It is of note this is only necessary for elements that do not automatically adjust their height via their content. The greatest offender of this is the jQuery tab in which, in my case, this issue occurs. Most non-manipulated relative height elements auto adjust their space as elements are toggled between display = block||none.

Here is some example code:

```
setElemHeight = function(options) { 
    var _elem = options.containerElement;
    var _nBase = options.nBaseHeight;
    var _nMltplr = options.nMultiplierHeight;
    // COUNT ROWS
    var _nCnt = 0;
    $( '#' + _elem.id + ' div div:first-child  > input').each( function() { 
        if(this.style.display != 'none') _nCnt++; 
    });
    $(_elem).height(_nBase + (_nCnt * _nMltplr));
}
```

I've abstracted out enough for my purposes but you could take it a little farther so the selector children elements are dynamic.